# Resharper inserting extra lines in CSS

Tags: resharper

My Resharper CSS configuration seems to have changed for my Visual Studio 2015 project (Resharper Ultimate 2016.2.2), so that any time I type a line in a CSS file and hit the semi-colon, it inserts a blank line above.  Additionally when I open a new pair of curly braces, it places a blank line above and below the new cursor position, in the following fashion:

```
.radio-list {

    *cursor*

}
```

The behaviour change only started recently and a fellow developer is also experiencing the same issue.  Any ideas on which Resharper option can be changed to reverse this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pin the issue down to a bug in the way Resharper is processing the comments in the css file.  I had a headline comment at the top of the file:

```
/* Comment */

/* Comment */
body.wait *, body.wait {
    cursor: wait !important;
}
```

Removing that blank line between the first two comments made the issue go away.  Putting something else like a space or another comment also fixes it.